# Spark JavaRDD.subtract() issue

Tags: apache-spark

```
    JavaSparkContext jsc = TestUtil.getJavaSparkContext("TestSparkHBase");//just gets the java spark context

    List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l1.add(1);
    l1.add(2);
    l1.add(3);
    l1.add(4);
    l1.add(5);


    List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    l1.add(1);
    l1.add(2);


    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd1 = jsc.parallelize(l1);
    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd2 = jsc.parallelize(l2);

    JavaRDD<Integer> rdd3 = rdd1.subtract(rdd2);
    rdd3.saveAsTextFile("...");
```

the output I am getting is:
1
1
2
2
3
4
5

Is this an expected behaviour? My expectation was to get:
3
4
5
as output

Answer (score 3):

You add 1, 2 again into your l1 mistakenly, after you create a new ArrayList l2.

Change that to l2, you will get the expected result.